# How to link 32-bit Nasm assembly object code on a 64-bit windows computer

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I found the following code from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/328714-my-program-keeps-crashing/.

```
            global  start

            ;~ msvcrt.dll
            extern  _printf
            %define printf _printf

            ;~ kernel32.dll
            extern ExitProcess, GetCommandLineW, LocalFree
            %define GetCommandLine GetCommandLineW

            ;~ shell32.dll
            extern CommandLineToArgvW
            %define CommandLineToArgv CommandLineToArgvW

            SECTION .data
            message     db      'Hello, World', 13, 10, 0
            fmtstr      db      "%s", 0
            fmtstrCL    db      "Arg","%d", " = ", "%S", 13, 10, 0

            section .bss
            pNumArgs    resd    1

            section .text
            start:

                call    GetCommandLine

                push    pNumArgs
                push    eax
                call    CommandLineToArgv
                mov     esi, eax

                mov     ebx, [pNumArgs]
            DisplayArgs:
                dec     ebx
                push    dword[esi + 4 * ebx]
                inc     ebx
                push    ebx
                push    fmtstrCL
                call    printf
                add     esp, 4 * 3
                dec     ebx
                jnz     DisplayArgs

                push    esi
                call    LocalFree   

                push    message                         ; Push address of "Hello, world!" onto the stack
                push    fmtstr                          ; push address of formatter onto the stack
                call    printf                          ; Print the message
                add     esp, 4 * 2                      ; adjust stack pointer

                push    0
                call    ExitProcess
```

My goal is to learn assembly language by reading other people's code and eventually write my own. I cannot figure out how to link 32-bit assembly programs on my 64-bit windows computer.

To assemble the program I use the command:

```
nasm -f win32 hello32.asm -o hello32.o
```

To link the object file I use:

```
gcc hello32.o -o hello32.exe
```

After I issue the link command I get the following error:

```
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/
gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 arc
hitecture of input file `hello32.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
hello32.o:hello32.asm:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `_printf'
hello32.o:hello32.asm:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `_printf'
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/
gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw3
2.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined refere
nce to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using 64-bit mingw binaries that are supposed to be compatible with making 32-bit programs. I have tried switching to 32-bit mingw binaries and I get a massive amount of undefined reference errors. I can link simple skeleton files without any problems using the above commands. I have no idea what I am doing wrong and I would appreciate any guidance someone could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i386 architecture of input file `hello32.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

NASM has created a 32 bit object file, but you are trying to link a 64 bit executable. You could try to use the `-m32` switch to create a 32 bit executable, but you already found out that this causes another bunch of errors. I do not have a solution for that either.

To link your executable, use a **32 bit MingW** environment. I tried MinGW4.6.2 32 bit which worked well. 
Alternatively, you can use the linker (`link.exe`) from a Microsoft Visual Studio installation.

https://github.com/afester/CodeSamples/tree/master/Asm/nasm_win32 shows a hello world example together with a Makefile which uses the Visual Studio linker. Alternatively, using `gcc  helloworld.obj -o hello32.exe` from a MingW32 installation works also.

Comment: Would I be better off to try and convert the program to 64-bit? I have tried to and I get only one error but I have no idea how to correct it either.

Comment: You can give it a try, but instruction set, registers, and calling convention are partially different. For example, `push eax` is not supported - you need to push the whole 64 bit register `push rax`. I would start with getting the 32 bit application to run.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try to get the 32-bit program to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Two issues:**

1. You're using the option `-f win32` but asking for the object file in `*.o` extension. The two formats, `.o` and `.obj` are not compatible. But of course, you're free to specify your own extension, and so `nasm` will obediently assemble your code into a file with i386 arc format `.o` file.
2. Next, you're asking `gcc` to build that hello32.exe, using the file hello32.o. Effectively, you gave gcc an arc format .o file, and asked to build a 64-bit PE format executable out of it. And then (naturally) gcc complains:

   i386 architecture of input file `hello32.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

which is correct.

**Two ways you can fix this:**

1. Assemble with: `nasm -fwin32 hello32.asm` and then, link with `gcc -m32 hello32.obj -o hello32.exe`
2. Assemble with: `nasm -fobj hello32.asm` and then link with `alink -subsys console -oPE hello32.o`. You can get alink [from here](http://alink.sourceforge.net).

Let me know which worked for you.

P.S. I have outlined the problems I have faced myself [in this blog](https://bitcodersblog.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/win32-in-nasm-part-1/), hope that helps.